# How to insert a date in a Date Type Column in HSQLDB Table using Hibernate?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, hsqldb

I'm trying to insert a Date type entry in a Column of a Table in HSQLDB. The issue is I'm using Hibernate to do so, can anyone please help me how to do that?

**The table is as follows:**

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(
WORKINGDATE DATE NOT NULL
)
```

**The Bean file is as follows:**

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {

    private Date workingDate;


    public Date getWorkingDate() {
        return workingDate;
    }

    public void setWorkingDate(Date workingDate) {
        this.workingDate = workingDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test [workingDate=" + workingDate + "]";
    }

}
```

**The XML Mapping is as follows:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="bean.hibpackage.Test" table="TEST">

        <property name="workingDate" column="WORKINGDATE" type="date" />

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Now the testing scenario is:**

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import bean.hibpackage.Test;

public class TestHibernate2 {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws ParseException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Test test = new Test();

        String date_s = "2015-02-22";

        {
        //How to format the above given string to a date type so that the
        //program will work
        }

        test.setWorkingDate(?);

        Session ses = null;

        try {
            SessionFactory sessions = null;
            sessions = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

            ses = sessions.openSession();

            Transaction tran = ses.beginTransaction();

            ses.save(test);

            tran.commit();
        } finally {
            ses.close();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to parse the `Date` string representation:

```
String date_s = "2015-02-22";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
test.setWorkingDate(sdf.parse(date_s));
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad, this was the first thing that I tried, & of course that is the solution. But the problem was with my Database Table & Hibernate XML Mapping class, as you can notice that there's no ID field in my XML File <class> </class> & I found that somehow Hibernate doesn't allow to connect to a DB table with no ID field, i.e. to connect with a DB table which has no Primary Key/Composite Key Column. Once i did that i was good to go! Thanks although because it was your reply that forced me to do a shallow Root Cause Analysis...

Comment: @DhirendraVerma: would you consider accepting this answer? To do so, click the tick mark to the left of the answer, so it turns green.